# Changing Number order in the same column in the ArcGIS Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, field-calculator, python-parser

I have two types of number in my shapefile/database in the same column as follows. The first one does not have any alphabetic character but second one has alphabetic characters.

```
(a) 26 25 21 0000 00200 0000
(b) 27 25 21 0050 00000 001A
```

There is one space between the blanks as it can be seen from the number. The number given are mismatched. Here, in the first example, the 21 should take the place of 26 and 26 should take the place of 21 and in second example, 21 should take place of 27 and vice-versa. For example, this is the output I am after:

```
(a) 2125260000002000000
(b) 212527005000000001A
```

How can I replace those numbers using the field calculator?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question is an issue related to [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), doesn't have a GIS component. You can ask in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead

Comment: @aldo_tapia I see this as more of a field calculator problem, which, in my opinion, is relevant to this forum. I made a few edits to hopefully address your concerns.

Comment: Thank you gusy, but it was a GIS problem. However, it has been solved by @ahmadhanb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using Field Calculator by creating new field and apply the following python code in the `Pre-Logic Script Code`:

```
def mod_txt(f):
    txt = f.split()
    if len(txt) > 0:
        newtxt = str(txt[2])+str(txt[1])+str(txt[0])+str(txt[3])+str(txt[4])+str(txt[5])
        return newtxt
    else:
        return ''
```

Write in the new field the following:

`mod_txt( !FieldName! )`

The code will split the text field using the spaces and will rearrange the string based on your requirement to replace the first number with the third one and vice-versa.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much@ahmadhanb for your help. It worked very nicely with a blink of eye. I spent several hours to figure it out.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it worked :)